# Infinite sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{n2^n}}$

Tags: summation

How do I evaluate this sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{n2^n}}$$

Comment: Hi. It would be nice to include your thoughts on the question.

Comment: Hint: Taylor expansion of $-\ln(1-x)$

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153499/show-ln2-sum-limitsn-1-infty-frac1n2n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{n2^n}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\int_0^{1/2}x^{n-1}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{1/2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{1/2}{\frac{1}{1-x}}}\,\mathrm{d}x=\ln{2}$$

Comment: This works in this case, but in general one must take care about the interchange between summation and integration. In particular, a sufficient condition is that the series $S(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent on the domain of integration. (being all $f_n$ continuous on the same region.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Think of this as the result of plugging $x=\frac{1}{2}$ in to a power series.