# How do I show that $\ln(2) = \sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n2^n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

My task is this:

Show that $$\ln(2) = \sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n2^n}$$

My work so far:

If we approximate $\ln(x)$ around $x = 1$, we get:

$\ln(x) = (x-1) - \frac{(x-1)^2}{2} + \frac{(x-1)^3}{3} - \frac{(x-1)^4}{4} + ...$

Substituting $x = 2$ then gives us:

$\ln(2) = 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} + ...$

No suprise there, we should always get alternating series for $\ln(x)$ when we are doing the taylor expansion. By using Euler transform which is shown at the middle of this page on [natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm) one can obtain the wanted result, but how do you derive it? I need someone to actually show and explain in detail how one starts from the left side of the equation and ends up on the other.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, your series is expanded in powers of $\frac{1}{2}$, and your $\ln x$ series is expanded in powers of $-(x-1)$ (noting that the signs of the coefficients alternate) - just choose a suitable $x$ to make these match up.

Comment: Hint: $\ln(\frac{x}{x-1})=-\ln(\frac{x-1}{x})=-\ln(1-\frac{1}{x})$

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153499/show-ln2-sum-limitsn-1-infty-frac1n2n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1-x}&=1+x+x^2+\cdots\qquad(-1<x<1).
\end{align}
Thus
\begin{align}
-\ln(1-x)&=\int\frac{1}{1-x}{\rm d}x\\
&=x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{3}x^3+\cdots\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}x^n.
\end{align}
By taking $x=\frac{1}{2}$ into the above equation, we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n2^n}=-\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\ln(2).$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may write

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n2^n}&=\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^{1/2}x^{n-1}dx
> \\\\&=\int_0^{1/2}\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1}\:dx
> \\\\&=\int_0^{1/2}\frac1{1-x}\:dx
> \\\\&=\left[-\ln(1-x)\right]_0^{1/2}
> \\\\&=\ln 2
> \end{align}
> $$

as wanted.

Similarly, one gets
$$
\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n}=-\ln(1-t),\quad |t|<1.
$$